# Clojure: How to get the metadata of inner function?

Tags: clojure

I have this code and would like to get the metadata transform

```
(defn truncate
  [& {:keys [len]}]
  (fn ^:transform [value]
    (clojure.string/join (take len value))))
```

Ex: (meta (var (truncate)) //doesn't work

Something like this is possible? (meta (meta (var truncate))

UPDATE:

I moved it top the function name and solved it this way:

```
(defn- func-meta [func]
  (let [[name-space func-name _] (clojure.string/split (str func) #"\$")]
    (meta (ns-resolve (symbol name-space) (symbol func-name)))))

(func-meta (transform/truncate)) ;=> metadata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching this type of metadata to arglists has no particular meaning in Clojure. (Type hints may be attached to arglists, but that's a different matter.) You can, however, attach metadata to the function itself using either of the following methods:

```
(defn foo []
  ^:foo (fn [] 1))

(defn foo []
  (with-meta (fn [] 1) {:foo 1}))

;; in either case:
(meta (foo))
;= {:foo true}
```

Also, the `var` special form gives convenient access to Vars:

```
(var +)
;= #'clojure.core/+
```

The `#'` shorthand notation is used much more frequently.